# Where do I get IVsSingleFileGenerator?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-generation

The docs say to look for "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop (in microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.dll)", but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 5):

Have you installed the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en)?

Comment: Nope. But that does sound promising.